# Select TOP @N where @N is a variable from another Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building a report on server hardware projections, and I'm getting stuck here.

I have a query that correctly returns the number of HDD's installed on the server, and am storing that number into a variable called `@OtherHDDs`, and it is an `INT`.

I need to now do this...

```
Select top @OtherHDDs.... 
from ...
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enclose the variable in parenthesis:

```
select top (@OtherHDDs) -- your column list here
from YourTable
```

[MSDN Reference on `SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)